# Does the singularities of black holes not being simply connected imply that the universal coverings of quantum field theory fail?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, lie-groups, mathematical-physics, general-relativity, quantum-field-theory

Does the singularities of black holes not being simply connected imply that the universal coverings of the usual types of Lie groups of quantum field theory fail?

I was downvoted and told that I need to give more detail, so please forgive me if I am being redundant or verbose.  Universal coverings require simple connectedness of the spaces they cover by definition.  The singularities of black holes (assuming all black holes rotate, and therefore have ring singularities) in the space means it is not simply connected, right?  Is there any way around this while keeping the universal coverings?

I'm still not sure why I'm being downvoted.  Maybe rewording will help: "Is it impossible to use a universal covering of a Lie group to construct a quantum field theory for gravity, given the ring singularities of rotating black holes?"

Comment: Well you really need to provide more details.

Comment: @JohnMa What's missing?  I thought it was pretty straightforward.

Comment: Which Lie groups of quantum field theory?  AFAIK there is no quantum field theory of gravitation.

Comment: Three-dimensional space with a point singularity removed is still simply connected.  To get something not simply connected you would have to remove something like a ring - which coincidentally is the singularity of a rotating (Kerr) black hole.

Comment: @Robert: What about gravioli in heavy cream?

Comment: @RobertIsrael Don't all black holes rotate?

Comment: @RobertIsrael Right, I'm trying to find out if universal coverings of Lie groups are not an option for a quantum field theory of gravity for this reason.

Comment: @user3146 In principle, there can be nonrotating black holes.  In practice, I suppose since almost everything in the universe has some angular momentum, almost every black hole will have some.